# Google Chrome extension that treats @user in the address bar as Twitter protocol?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions

I'm wondering if there's any Google Chrome extensions that treat queries prefixed with `@` as a request for a Twitter username, and request the correct Twitter user's page. I've had a look around in the Google Chrome Store, but haven't managed to find anything that fits this description.

Any info would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options -> Basics -> Manage Search Engines. Create an entry for Twitter and give it a keyword (such as @). For the URL, enter this: `http://twitter.com/#!/%s`. Now, type in your keyword and hit Tab, and then type in the username and hit Enter.